# Why does Florence Faivre maintain a regular cast credit in 'The Expanse'?

Tags: casting, the-expanse

So, despite having reached the middle of Season 3 of *The Expanse*, I have been particularly befuddled at the continuing presence of Florence Faivre's primary credit during the shows opening titles. While I am sure that I have probably missed minor images of her character Julie Mao during S2, the only time I can remember her appearing in any significance was during the episode in which Miller persuaded her to take the alternative road trip to Venus. With Miller's current absence it was instantly notable that Thomas Janes top credit was removed and replaced by Steven Strait's by the following episode.

Despite the fact that I am sure that Mao (Jr.) and Miller will be seen again at some point, I cannot recall seeing her since 'Home'. I get that that the proto - chatter occasionally heard probably contains dialogue from Faivre but is this the reason that she retains a top credit through the remainder of S2 and (so far) S3 or am I missing something else?

Or is it simply a contract issue which sees her getting paid as a regular cast member despite not (to my knowledge) doing anything? I am currently about to start S3's 'Triple Point' so any spoiler material subsequent to that episode would preferably be avoidable...

Comment: It's very probably contractual. Hard to say much more without plot spoilers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not saying there are related spoilers, but I am wanting to point out that by people not wanting to write spoilers if there were any, you're never sure if you get the full answer or not. Yes, I would write this regardless of whether there are spoilers or not (because otherwise it defeats the purpose).

That being said, any question about names in credits *always* hinges on what was contractually agreed. Whether it's about appearance, order, or prefixes (e.g. "*with* John Smith"), it's always something that is agreed between the show runners and the actors.